# Image & Text button - no image appears - tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button

It's my first post here, I also have a puzzlement about the code below.
I don't have the image displayed next to the text, the button is properly displayed (p.s : why the height and width have to be adjusted again, for example the button without the picture has width = 22 and height = 2, when I put the picture to be visible I have 200 by 200, well it can be a bit smaller), I have the text displayed, but the picture is missing...Could it be from .grid?

```
bl_logo = Image.open('img/balance.png')
bl_logo = bl_logo.resize((25,25), Image.ANTIALIAS)
balance_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bl_logo)
buttons_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg = "#004d4d")
balance_btn = tk.Button(buttons_frame, image = balance_img, compound = tk.LEFT, text = 'BALANCE', font = ('Bebas NEUE', 20), width = 220, height = 200)
balance_btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx = 10, pady = (60,40)
```

Comment: Is this code inside a function?

Comment: @BryanOakley inside a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the balance_img in the widget class to prevent it from the garbage collector.

add this line `balance_btn.image = balance_img`

```py
bl_logo = Image.open('img/balance.png')
bl_logo = bl_logo.resize((25,25), Image.ANTIALIAS)
balance_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bl_logo)
buttons_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg = "#004d4d")
balance_btn = tk.Button(buttons_frame, image = balance_img, compound = tk.LEFT, text = 'BALANCE', font = ('Bebas NEUE', 20), width = 220, height = 200)
balance_btn.image = balance_img
balance_btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx = 10, pady = (60,40)
```

I already answer this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73605081/why-is-this-python-tkinter-function-not-using-the-given-image/73605104#73605104) to another user.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Can you also tell me why it is necessary to change the width and height?

Comment: @CMarian size of the master widget(in this case `main_frame`) is depends on the child widgets so you have to change the size of your widget.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm just starting out so I'm sorry if I sound like a mess